# Saving data inside user session getting shared between user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish

i am having one jsp file with the following code

```
String name=request.getParameter("user");
  if(name==null)
    name=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
  else
    request.getSession().setAttribute("name", name);
```

i assume if the page get any request with user as parameter, it will save the value to that particular user session and in case the get request is not having any 'user' parameter it will try to read the user value from the session. The code is working perfectly when i host it from my local server(glassfish). 
But when i upload it into some remote host, things are getting weird.
When i hit the page with parameter 'user', its saving the value in the session. But then again if i hit the page from some other browser(or after clearing cookie), its retrieving the previous value saved, instead of returning null
Am i doing something wrong, actually im pretty new to Java EE.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get previous value saved unless
1) Your session is not finished and same session is getting extended. Can you explain how you are clearing the cookies.
2) Are you typing the URL or trying to refresh the page after deleting the cookies.

Comment: i'm not clearing the cookies at all. I first hit the page from chrome like mypage?user='chrome'. Then the value 'chrome' will be saved in the session. Next i try to hit the page from firefox like mypage(with out any parameters). Here the code request.getSession().getAttribute("name") returns 'chrome'. According to me it must return null.

Comment: @Arshed Are you sure you don't have an old session sitting around in Firefox where you just happened to use "chrome" as the user's name? Try printing out the session's "id" in your page to help see what's going on.

Comment: chances are there for some old session, but how come it get the new value.